# Font package in lualatex gives the cm style figure

Tags: fonts, luatex, font-encodings

I want to use the `FiraSans` font as main text font and the `newtx` as the math font in my pgfplots figure. Because the data file contains much points I use the `lualatex` as the compiler for it can dynamically adjust the memory, here is the mwe

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage[sfdefault,scaled=.85]{FiraSans}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxsf}
\begin{document}

test
\[
a^2+b^2=c^2
\]
\end{document}
```

But the font package seems not work well.
[image]
 The text and the figures is still in the cm style. If I use `pdflatex` all is right. Two warning informations appear when I use `lualatex`

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/FiraSans(0)/m/n' undefined(Font) 
LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.
```

How can I use the font package with the `lualatex`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should load `newtxsf` before `FiraSans` and pass `no-math` to `fontspec`.

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[tikz,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\usepackage[cmintegrals]{newtxsf}
\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}
\usepackage[sfdefault,scaled=.85]{FiraSans}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

test $a^2+b^2=c^2$

\end{document}
```

[image]

You don't need `\PassOptionsToPackage{no-math}{fontspec}` if you add the option as a global one:

```
\documentclass[tikz,12pt,no-math]{standalone}
```

Comment: your solution solves the problems, thanks :-)

Answer (score 4):

This answer solves the problem with the font warnings and the text uses font FiraSans instead of Computer Modern. However, it does not solve the problem with the wrong font for the figures in math style.

Font encoding `T1` is intended for fonts with at most 256 slots, therefore package `fontspec` uses a different font encoding. Package `FiraSans` uses `fontspec` if it detects a TeX compiler capable of using OpenType fonts (LuaTeX, XeTeX).

As solution, `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` can be wrapped in:

```
\usepackage{ifluatex, ifxetex}
\newif\ifWithOpenTypeFonts
\ifluatex
  \WithOpenTypeFontstrue
\else
  \ifxetex
    \WithOpenTypeFontstrue
  \fi
\fi
\ifWithOpenTypeFonts
  % \usepackage{fontspec}
\else
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi
```

Then the document can be compiled with the different TeX compilers.

Comment: thanks for your answer. When I replace the `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with the code you give, and use the `lualatex` as the compiler, the error message says that `Incomplete \iftrue; all text was ignored after line xx` where xx is the location of `\else\ifxetex`

Comment: @Ice0cean: There is a \fi missing.